# How to Extend the Google Calendar API Holiday Year Range

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Im Using the Google Calendar API To get Holidays in my Country but I cant seem to extend the duration past 2023 or CurrentYear + 1.

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.sa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=InsertGoogleAPIkeyHere

Anyone Know how to Extend the API duration or implemented extended durations past the default API limitations? Maybe a Paid version of sorts.

Comment: Have you tried using [`timeMax` and `timeMin` parameters](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list#parameters)?

Comment: I have no @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou Let me give it a try

Comment: Could u Provide with an example of how to implement max E.g Where it Falls in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Calendar holiday calendars are generated by google.  They have a limited length.  they do not go more then a year into the future or a year in the past.

You can see that by checking the Google calendar web site.

2022 and 2023 are set

[image]

2024 is not

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I Thought as much. Sucks but still better then 200$ a year for 2 years into the future

Comment: I think there is an outstanding feature request for a few years ago requesting that they go 10 years into the future.

Comment: That would be awesome But I do guess its a rather niche  feature.